# Unsure how to make custom <div> with scalable background

Tags: html, css

Have been attempting to make a custom sidebar similar to the image linked below. However I'm unsure of how to go about coding the custom div (if even necessary) and incorporating a variable border.

I have tried managing multiple s to achieve the slanted header but to no success. 
I have considered the option of just using the template as a background image but I'm not sure if that is the best approach as I would ideally like the sidebar to be scalable due to drop down menus.

I apologize if this isn't a wealth of information but I am just clueless as how to accomplish an end result. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

http://oi47.tinypic.com/wjce1j.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by

1, make a div for header like

[image]

2, make left and right side div with 100% height and repeat this image both side

> [image]

it would be like

[image]

Comment: Oh wow I feel blind. Such a simple solution works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use images, you should be able to accomplish this with just css and html. The benefit to doing this with css and html is that it will re-size in the browser better (although newer browsers are getting better at re-sizing images) and take no time to load.

You could try something along the lines of the following.

Here are the CSS styles:

```
#tabbox {
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid #C7ECFE;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-4px 6px 12px #C7ECFE; 
    -moz-box-shadow: -4px 6px  12px #C7ECFE; 
    box-shadow:-4px 6px  12px #C7ECFE; 
}
#tabbox:before {
    margin-top:-2px;
    margin-left:0px;
    height: 0;
    width: 143px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute; 
    border-bottom: 30px solid #C7ECFE;
   border-right: 60px solid black; 
}
#tabbox:after {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 0;
    width: 142px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute; 
    border-bottom: 30px solid black;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
}
```

And then in your body just define the div with id = "tabbox". This will give you something like this:

[image: Sample Box]

Comment: I was browsing around before and I actually came across something very similar to this but couldn't achieve what I wanted. I'll give this a go because it would be nicer to have everything done in CSS/Html, cheers.